# Gauging the one form symmetries in the GKSW paper

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, topological-field-theory

Following is few of the many questions I have regarding the paper "Generalized Global Symmetry" by Gaitto et al. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.5148).

In Sec. 4 of the paper they considered the Maxwell theory.
$$
S=\frac{1}{2g^2}\int F\wedge *F
$$
with $F=dA$.

**The global  1-form symmetries:**

1. As they say, this has a one form symmetry $A\to A+\lambda_e$ where $\lambda_e$ is a closed 1-form. The corresponding conserved current is $J_e=*F$ which follows from the E.O.M. They call it the "electric 1-form symmetry".

2. From the Bianchi identity $dF=0$, we have another conserved current $J_m=F$ which defines the Magnetic one form symmetry.

I have the following questions related to the guaging of these 1-form symmetries.

**Guaging of the 1-form symmetries:**

1. If we guage the electric symmetry by allowing $d\lambda_e \neq 0$ we have to couple the theory to a guage field $B_e$ and consider the action
   $$
   S=\frac{1}{2g^2}\int (F-B_e) \wedge *(F-B_e).
   $$
   Now, am I correct in concluding that, now the conserved electric current should be taken to be $J_e'=*(F-B_e)$ ?
2. What should be the procedure to guage the Magnetic 1-form symmetry? What plays the roll of the guage symmetry parameter here (the analogue of $\lambda_e$)? It is tempting to define a magnetic guage field $\tilde{A}$ so that $*F=d\tilde{A}$. In terms of this, the magnetic symmetry can be defined as $\tilde{A} \to \tilde{A}+\lambda_m$. However, I am not sure whether we are allowed to do that. Since $d*F=0$ is not automatically zero, it is the equation of motion.
3. They also claim that we cannont guage both the electric and magnetic 1-form symmetry because of a mixed 't hooft anomaly. I could not attempt to understand this due to my concern mentioned in point. 2 above.

If someone can clarify these issues, it will be very helpful.

Comment: I'm curious as to how you managed to make the same typo *six* times...

Comment: What typo are you referring to?

Comment: guage${}{}{}{}$